# Story based in the future where magic is facilitated by microscopic computers

Tags: story-identification, novel

So I read a couple of ebooks many years ago which described a sort of a post-apocalyptic earth where (it is later revealed) magic is facilitated by a nano computers which realize the will of the user (presumably by reading their mind, or through incantations, maybe some sort of matrix... I don't recall exactly). 
The experiment I suppose had gone wrong and wiped out many humans and created many Gods.

The story also featured Gods who acted more like egoistical overpowered mafia bosses running some sort of insurance businesses.

The protagonist (or one of them, I don't recall)  was an uber powerful god who wiped his own memory for some reason(can't recall why) and lived as a human. He was also one of the scientists pre apocalypse who worked on the project that created the computers

Also I think technological advancement as illegal as it was seen threatening to Gods.

Also most of the humans had no idea about the experiment or the times before the catastrophy. 
Technology was rather primitive compared to modern times.

Comment: I think I remember this one. The gods were walled off in a sort of enclosure. The title character had become infected with the nano-virus and had become a god for a short period of time before the government stepped in. There was a reference to babies getting the god disease and refusing to be born. If memory serves, it was a scottish author or set in scotland near the coast.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Don't remember that part. But it may have been there. Though I think the experiment killed off most of humanity

Answer (score 5):

This could be *Lord of Light* by Roger Zelazny.

> So I read a couple of ebooks many years ago which described a sort of a post-apocalyptic earth where (it is later revealed) magic is facilitated by a nano computers which realize the will of the user (presumably by reading their mind, or through incantations, maybe some sort of matrix... I don't recall exactly). The experiment I suppose had gone wrong and wiped out many humans and created many Gods.

The means of the technology isn’t specified that I recall, but certain colonists are immortal (transfer consciousness to new bodies at the end of each life or sooner), and the general population is taught Hinduism and sees it as factually true—not knowing about technology.

> The story also featured Gods who acted more like egoistical overpowered mafia bosses running some sort of insurance businesses.

I don’t know about insurance businesses (sounds more like Heinlein’s *Magic, Inc.*) but the attitude fits.

> The protagonist (or one of them, I don't recall) was an uber powerful god who wiped his own memory for some reason(can't recall why) and lived as a human. He was also one of the scientists pre apocalypse who worked on the project that created the computers

That was Sam.  He had the unique ability to control the native inhabitants of the planet, called demons, who were made of energy rather than matter.  He was cast out of the technological “heaven” where the “Gods” stay (his memories and consciousness transferred to electronic clouds), but one computer genius also of the original colonists devised a mechanism to bring him back and place him in a new body to overthrow heaven.

> Also I think technological advancement as illegal as it was seen threatening to Gods.

Precisely.  Printing press was illegal, too.

> Also most of the humans had no idea about the experiment or the times before the catastrophy. Technology was rather primitive compared to modern times.

Yes.  These last two paragraphs match the most perfectly.

Comment: No, it wasn't this one. There was no hinduism involved. ALthough the universe is awfully similar

Answer (score 4):

This could be the story [*Ra*](https://qntm.org/ra) written by Sam Hughes and published online.
He is currently in the process of rewriting the last few chapters, BTW.

It features a current-day world, but with magic, which was discovered in the 70's and scientifically studied. As it turns out later, the world is actually recreated many thousands of years in the future after a catastrophic insurrection of uploaded humans and magic is the intentionally complicated access to the all-powerful DWIM (do-what-i-mean) computer.

One of the creators lived a normal life and is the mother of the protagonist.

Comment: I read the first couple chapters a long time ago.  Your answer is very spoilery, but I’ll forgive that because it sounds awesome and I might not have finished without the spoiler.  :)

Comment: i had it spoilered first, but since the important points are the similarities with the question, i think it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Idlewild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idlewild_(novel)) by Nick Sagan. The all trilogy fits your description pretty well. 2nd and 3rd books are [Edenborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edenborn) and [Everfree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everfree).

The main character is Hal (short for Halloween) who starts the story with no memory. He lives in a strange world with others students, divided in domains. They can generate things at will like magic, because (we learn that later in the story) they are in a sort of Matrix-thing. Hal lives with nightgaunts in his domain and plays a sort of conquest game with the other students . They take classes, and there are murders.

The matrix thing is revealed late in the first book. They live in this cocoon to learn things that might help them to recreate the humanity, wiped out by a virus. They have been created to be immunised to this virus and they will bring back cryogenised rich people from the past. They are more than humans, so they are like gods.

They try to create a civilised world, but they don't agree with each other and the reborn people are not easy to manage, so they rule the city with a sort of mafia. They dreamt of an utopia, but it doesn't work. (2nd book)

I don't have many memories of the third book. They are separated. I think they leave the city of the 2nd book. The world is divided between them, and they are all not sane. There is something involving a clone, and a mad girl who  keeps things that she finds "nutritive" or "delicious". If something is not, she gets rid of it.

[Here is a summary from a person who freshly read it](https://redshirtcrew.wordpress.com/category/idlewild/) that briefly covers the three books.

Comment: Could you provide some more details (like in the above) that suggest the similarity between the books you're suggesting and the book that as described in the original question?

Comment: English is not my first language and my memories are not perfect, but I put some details :)

Comment: Don't worry, we can always help with editing anything that needs cleaning up, thanks for being so understanding

Comment: Thanks but its not this one. Mine does start with the character having no memory of who he is, but this wasn't a VR, it was the real world.